# R Selecting columns of a data frame based on a vector

Tags: r, plyr, apply

I have an example data frame as shown below.

```
> x=data.frame(id=1:5,c1=letters[1:5],c2=letters[13:17])
> x
  id c1 c2
1  1  a  m
2  2  b  n
3  3  c  o
4  4  d  p
5  5  e  q
```

I want to create a vector out of this data frame which selects a different column for each row based on another vector. So if that vector is

```
> vars
[1] 1 2 2 1 1 
>
```

I want for the 1st row in x, column 1, for the second row in x, column 2 and so on. So the expected output vector (or data frame) would be
if vector

```
a n o d e
```

if data frame

```
id V1
 1  a
 2  n
 3  o
 4  d
 5  e
```

Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can 'slice' a data frame using a matrix:

```
y=data.frame(1:5,c(1,2,2,1,1))
x[2:3][as.matrix(y)]
```

result:

```
[1] "a" "n" "o" "d" "e"
```

Let's generalise this by creating a function

```
selector=function(x)matrix(c(seq_along(x),x),ncol=2)
```

Note that there is one column to be ignored at the start, so add 1 to your select vector v

```
v=c(1,2,2,1,1)
x[selector(v+1)]
```

result

```
[1] "a" "n" "o" "d" "e"
```